# Parent/Child on same Case object : NullPointerException: Attempt to de-Reference a null object

Tags: apex, soql

My question is continuation of what I have asked [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116478/how-to-define-a-map-with-id-and-listcase-of-records)

How do I replace from:

```
parentChildCase.get(cMap.get(c).ID).add(cMap.get(c));
```

to this Id (`pId`):

```
Map<id, id> par = new Map<id, id>();  

List <case> rcases =[SELECT ... FROM CASE WHERE <other_conditions....>];
for (case c : rcases) {
  par.put(c.id,c.ParentId);
}

Id = pId = par.get(cMap.get(c).Parentid);
```

Error `NullPointerException: Attempt to de-Reference a null object`

```
for(ID c : cMap.keySet()) 
{
    if(parentChildCase.containsKey(cMap.get(c).ID)) 
    {
        //parentChildCase.get(cMap.get(c).ID).add(cMap.get(c));
        Id pId = par.get(cMap.get(c).Parentid);
        parentChildCase.get(pId).add(cMap.get(c)); //ERROR      NullPointerException: Attempt to de-Reference a null object
    }
    else
    {
        List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
        cases.add(cMap.get(c));
        parentChildCase.put(cMap.get(c).ID, cases);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have a null reference is because of this

```
if(parentChildCase.containsKey(cMap.get(c).ID))   // **you are checking for the key 
    {
        //parentChildCase.get(cMap.get(c).ID).add(cMap.get(c));
        Id pId = par.get(cMap.get(c).Parentid);
       // **you are inserting on a different key here
        parentChildCase.get(pId).add(cMap.get(c)); //ERROR      NullPointerException: Attempt to de-Reference a null object
    }
```

If my understanding is correct you wanna create a map of `Map<pID, List<Case>>`

All you need to loop in your Map keys and create a new Map

```
Map<Id, List<Case>> PIDMap = new Map<Id, List<Case>>();
for(ID c : cMap.keySet()) 
{
    if(parentChildCase.containsKey(cMap.get(c).ID)) 
    {
      Id pId = par.get(cMap.get(c).Parentid); 
      PIDMap.put(pID,parentChildCase.get(cMap.get(c).ID) );
    }
}
```

Comment: the way i wanted to have output is pareidId: {child case},{child case}, like one to many relationship so I should be able to pull one parent id has 1 or more child cases. if you look at my question I have the link and it will take you to my original question.. as i said its continuation of my question, in this question, I just wanted to change to correct ParentId

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean exactly...

Comment: in other words, how can i replace from `parentChildCase.get(cMap.get(c).ID).add(cMap.get(c));` to this `par.get(cMap.get(c).Parentid);`